# HTAccess login when enabling "Secure URLs in Admin"

Tags: magento-1.14

I'm not a Magento guy, but I'm working on a Magento server for my company's customer. I have few questions as below:

- Should I put HTTPS prefix instead of HTTP into the "Secure Base URL" field?
- When I set the "Secure Base URL" to HTTPS then turn on "Use Secure URLs in Frontend" and "Use Secure URLs in Admin", it asks for a username and password before displaying the login dialog of admin page. I think it's some kinds of htaccess configured automatically by Magento when turning on the secure URL. But where is that authentication file? And is there any default login?

Magento version on this server is 1.14.

Thank you very much for helping me on this topic. I'm really dumb about this point :).

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it should be https.
2. You should look for a .htpasswd file if what you are seeing is a basic http auth. It might be located in the .htaccess or maybe in the vhost. I don't think this is related to question nr 1.

Comment: Thank you :). Actually I don't have any htaccess restriction in the VHOST. Only when turning on those features it asks the credential. I notice that there an .htaccess file in the document root of website come from Magento installation, but there is no username or hashed password inside.